Video doesn't start playing when scrolling into view ONLY mobile devices
I am experiencing problems in the mobile version. From desktop to scroll the video starts correctly but from mobile it doesn't work. Searching I also found this question but it did not lead to the solution. I appreciate any suggestions, thank you
jQuery(window).on("load", function() {
var distance = jQuery('#page00').offset().top;

jQuery(window).scroll(function () {
    if (jQuery(window).scrollTop() >= distance) {
        if (jQuery("#page00").hasClass("stopVid")) {}else{
            jQuery('#page00').addClass("stopVid");
            jQuery("#videoHero0").get(0).play();
        }
    } else {
        jQuery('#page00').removeClass("stopVid");
    }
});
    } );

Codepen: https://codepen.io/documarketing/pen/xxoKVKN
Current code:


jQuery(window).on("load", function() {
var distance = jQuery('#page00').offset().top;

jQuery(window).scroll(function () {
    if (jQuery(window).scrollTop() >= distance) {
        if (jQuery("#page00").hasClass("stopVid")) {}else{
            jQuery('#page00').addClass("stopVid");
            jQuery("#videoHero0").get(0).play();
        }
    } else {
        jQuery('#page00').removeClass("stopVid");
    }
});
    } );
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="height:1050px"></div> 
<div id="page00">
<video preload="auto" title="Video" class="video" id="videoHero0" muted="muted" playsinline controls>
     
    <source src="https://v.ftcdn.net/05/01/76/22/700_F_501762204_Puv22dfipqai5oNxpb2Uamqx6GHWp110_ST.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        <source src="https://v.ftcdn.net/05/01/76/22/700_F_501762204_Puv22dfipqai5oNxpb2Uamqx6GHWp110_ST.webm" type="video/webm">
  </video>
</div>
<div style="height:1050px"></div>




@darkbee https://codepen.io/documarketing/pen/xxoKVKN

I created a pen with the video I am working with, simply when I try from mobile the video does not start while if I use the mobile version from desktop it works

okay, thank you, I changed

I may be remembering incorrectly, but I have a vague memory that most mobile browsers only trigger a scroll event once a scroll is complete, as an optimisation technique. Are you expecting the video to play mid-scroll?

Yes, I have an initial graphic the moment the video gets to the top it should start the video automatically
